# How to call a C function that uses a callback in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, c2hs

I am trying to call the following `C` function from `Haskell` using `c2hs`.

```
void rd_kafka_conf_set_rebalance_cb (
    rd_kafka_conf_t *conf,
    void (*rebalance_cb) (rd_kafka_t *rk,
                          rd_kafka_resp_err_t err,
                          rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_t *partitions,
                          void *opaque));
```

I am not familiar with `c2hs` and am having troubles with declaring bindings.

This is what I've tried:

```
--callback type
type RebalanceCbFun = 
    Ptr RdKafkaT -> CInt -> Ptr RdKafkaTopicPartitionListT -> Ptr Word8 -> IO ()

foreign import ccall safe "wrapper" 
    mkRebalanceCallback :: RebalanceCbFun -> IO (FunPtr RebalanceCbFun)

foreign import ccall unsafe "rd_kafka.h &rd_kafka_conf_set_rebalance_cb"
    rdKafkaConfSetRebalanceCb :: Ptr RdKafkaConfT -> FunPtr RebalanceCbFun -> IO ()
```

However I have the following error while compiling this code:

```
Unacceptable type in foreign declaration:
  ‘Ptr RdKafkaConfT
   -> FunPtr
        (Ptr RdKafkaT
         -> Int32 -> Ptr RdKafkaTopicPartitionListT -> Ptr Word8 -> IO ())
   -> IO ()’ cannot be marshalled in a foreign call
  A foreign-imported address (via &foo) must have type (Ptr a) or (FunPtr a)
When checking declaration:
  foreign import ccall unsafe "static rd_kafka.h &rd_kafka_conf_set_rebalance_cb" rdKafkaConfSetRebalanceCb
    :: Ptr RdKafkaConfT -> FunPtr RebalanceCbFun -> IO ()
```

I don't understand what part is missing `Ptr` or `FunPtr` here.
I also tried to wrap the whole `rdKafkaConfSetRebalanceCb` into `FunPtr` like:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "rd_kafka.h &rd_kafka_conf_set_rebalance_cb"
    rdKafkaConfSetRebalanceCb :: FunPtr (Ptr RdKafkaConfT -> FunPtr RebalanceCbFun -> IO ())
```

Not sure if it makes sense although it compiles... 
But then I don't know how to use this function, this is what I tried (and this is the signature I'd like to have in the end):

```
kafkaConfSetRebalanceCb :: RdKafkaConfTPtr -> RebalanceCbFun -> IO ()
kafkaConfSetRebalanceCb conf cb = do
    cb' <- mkRebalanceCallback cb
    withForeignPtr conf $ \c -> rdKafkaConfSetRebalanceCb c cb'
    return ()
```

Now it complains that I don't have a function to call, just a pointer to a function (because of that `FunPtr` wrapping).

Can you show me how `C` bindings could be done correctly for the `C` signature above?

Comment: Note for future visitors: C functions that will call back into Haskell code like this must not be imported `unsafe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following file compiles fine for me (with `ghc -c Test.hs`). The only real difference is that I have omitted the `&` in the foreign import.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Test where
import Data.Word
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.ForeignPtr

newtype RdKafkaT = RdKafkaT (Ptr RdKafkaT)
newtype RdKafkaConfT = RdKafkaConfT (Ptr RdKafkaConfT)
newtype RdKafkaTopicPartitionListT = RdKafkaTopicPartitionListT (Ptr RdKafkaTopicPartitionListT)

type RebalanceCbFun = 
    Ptr RdKafkaT -> CInt -> Ptr RdKafkaTopicPartitionListT -> Ptr Word8 -> IO ()

foreign import ccall safe "wrapper" 
    mkRebalanceCallback :: RebalanceCbFun -> IO (FunPtr RebalanceCbFun)

foreign import ccall unsafe "rd_kafka.h rd_kafka_conf_set_rebalance_cb"
    rdKafkaConfSetRebalanceCb :: Ptr RdKafkaConfT -> FunPtr RebalanceCbFun -> IO ()

kafkaConfSetRebalanceCb :: ForeignPtr RdKafkaConfT -> RebalanceCbFun -> IO ()
kafkaConfSetRebalanceCb conf cb = do
    cb' <- mkRebalanceCallback cb
    withForeignPtr conf $ \c -> rdKafkaConfSetRebalanceCb c cb'
```

Comment: Wow, indeed! I haven't even noticed that it was there! Thank you very much!